# "OR" filter with match phrase prefix in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do an Elasticsearch query wherein i want to do an OR filter

imagine i have this kind of documents

```
[ {name : "John Doe"}, {name :"Jane Doe"}, {name:"Steve Doe"} ]
```

A query that does the same thing with this SQL Query

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name LIKE 'Ja%' OR name LIKE 'Jo%'
```

Right now i'm using elasticsearch's match_phrase_prefix for the LIKE but i'm quite stuck with the OR.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bool should` query for implementing the `OR` operation. You can actually make use of `prefix` query instead of `match_phrase_prefix` for what you've described. Anyways, if you still find use case for a `match_phrase_prefix` query just replace the `prefix` query in the request below with `match_phrase_prefix` query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": {
              "value": "ja"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": {
              "value": "jo"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```